# ajax Combobox not firing event when combobox is empty

Tags: asp.net

In my .aspx I've written the following:

```
<ajaxToolkit:ComboBox ID="cmbAddressAlias" runat="server" DropDownStyle="Simple"      AutoCompleteMode="Suggest" CaseSensitive="false" AutoPostBack="true" RenderMode="Inline" Width="170px" CssClass="cmbProvince" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cmbAddressAlias_SelectedIndexChanged">           </ajaxToolkit:ComboBox>
```

It's binding correctly (datasource dynamically binded) and it raises event too, while changing index.

However it's not raising the event when I manually clear the combobox text.

If currently combobox having text "ASP" then I manually select that entire text and using del key I am deleting but it is not raising event for me. When I change index it automatically raises the event.

I need to raise the event while combobox is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You should handle this event as well "OnTextChanged" and note that it's different than "OnSelectedIndexChanged" which has been handled by you. Handle this event and it will fire when you clear the text on the combo.

And if the above does not work [this post](http://forums.asp.net/p/1464321/3374160.aspx) might help you.